# How i do Required If validation by function in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, foolproof-validation

if email exist by function check i want display error

how i do it?

```
 [RequiredIf(BL.datafuncs.checkIfExist(email) == true, ErrorMessage = "email already exist")]

 public string email { get; set; }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Sound like you want a `[Remote]` attribute that checks if an email already exists in the database and display error if it does. That's not what `[RequiredIf]` is for

Answer (score 2):

The `RequiredIf` attribute is for validating a property that is required based on the value of another property. For example if you model contains properties `bool NotifyMeByEmail` and `string EmailAddess` then you could apply it as follows.

```
public bool NotifyMeByEmail { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("NotifyMeByEmail", ErrorMessage = "Please enter you email address")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Then in the view, if the checkbox for `NotifyMeByEmail` is not checked, a validation error is generated for `EmailAddress`.

It looks like you actually want to validate the the email enter by the user does not already exist in he database, in which case you need a `[Remote]` attribute (standard MVC, not foolproof). [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Custom attributes are embedded in the assembly, they are not run time stuff, so you can NEVER put a function inside the attribute argument. I would suggest you do the check in your controller call and perform some action accordingly